# File Partioning

Tags: hard-drive

I'm just asking if what is the appropriate file system should I use in using ubuntu 12.04 because I can't install ubuntu on my Virtual machine and it say's " No root file system  is defined Please correct it from the partitioning menu"

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to define path. While installing Ubuntu, you should mention mount path
"/" There must be this option in dropdown menu.

View this to be more clear.

http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/step-by-step-beginners-guide-to-installing-ubuntu-11-10.172128/

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu 12.04 runs on ext4 file systems

Comment: it doesn't I dont know why.. Should I mount it?